# Node js однопоточен, а php многопоточен?

Tags: php, node.js

Сервер на nodejs при подключении нового клиента вызывает коллбек, в котором обрабатывается запрос. Если в коллбеке есть тяжелые вычисления, которые занимают много времени, то все остальные клиенты, подключившиеся после, будут поставлены в очередь в event loop и только после завершения текущего коллбека будет выполнен следующий.

В php же, даже если в скрипте есть тяжелые вычисления, то два разных клиента будут обслужены параллельно, не дожидаясь выполнения друг друга.

Можно ли такого добиться в nodejs?

Comment: Лучше просто избегать тяжёлых вычислений что в nodejs, что в php

Comment: Можно тяжелые вычисления вынести в сишный модуль, в котором выполнять их в отдельном потоке [например](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rectangle-bin-pack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).

Или, если подойти к этому с другой стороны, раз уж речь зашла про php, то более похожим по логике работы было бы:

1. Запустить несколько node.js серверов на разных портах.
2. С помощью nginx балансить запросы между этими приложениями.

В 10.5 появилась возможность [потоки/воркеры создавать](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), но фича пока экспериментальна, использовать не советую.